# MahApps.Metro window not showing with version 2.2.0 when used in different thread

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a custom metrowindow that acts as a splash screen. This is started in different thread. However, execution does not happen after I call the Show() function. I mean the window doesn't show.

```
protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    string g = null;

    var t = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(g);

    bool createdNew;
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "WpfApp1", out createdNew);
    if (!createdNew)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not allowed");
        this.Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
        Window1 testWindow = null;
        var m1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            testWindow = new Window1();
            testWindow.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
            testWindow.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml") });
            testWindow.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml") });
            testWindow.SetResourceReference(MetroWindow.BorderBrushProperty, "AccentColorBrush");
            testWindow.Show();
            m1.Set();
            // When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
            testWindow.Closed += (s, k) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
            };
            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t1.IsBackground = true;
        t1.Start();
        m1.WaitOne();

        Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Current.MainWindow.ShowDialog();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Things work perfectly if I use wpf window. Worst things is the same code works if I use version 1.5.6.0, without assigning the resources to tempWindow and defining the resources in app.xaml.

```
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

Comment: All UI activity in WPF should be performed on the main thread. Use a background thread (or an async method) to fetch data, but update the UI on the main thread.

Comment: I donot understand why the same code works with one version of mahpapp.metro and doesn't with another..What should do to make it work in the latest version

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to put such code in a different thread?

Comment: this is example..I have an application where changing it would require a lot of effort. We are upgrading from 1.6.5.0 to 2.2.0.0